# Looking for a more efficient way to check whether a string is a palindrome using STL functions

Tags: c++

I implemented the following code which works.

```
bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string rstr = str;
    reverse(rstr.begin(), rstr.end());
    if (str == rstr)
        return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? Specifically with functions from the string class.

For example, instead of creating a new variable to store the reversed string, do something like?

```
if (str == std::string{ reverse{str.begin(), str.end()})
```

I know this wont work since str is a reference to a const string.
I couldn't find any code that utilizes the STL functions to solve this in a better way.

Another question, why cant I do something like this instead of if statements?

```
str == rstr ? return true : return false;
```

Comment: Well, you could `return (str == rstr) ? true : false;`

Comment: You can construct a `string` using reverse iterators from the original string. Also, you can do `return str == rstr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::equal(str.begin(), str.begin()+str.size()/2, str.rbegin(), str.rbegin()+str.size()/2);
```

`std::equal` take 4 iterators in 2 pairs.  It compares the first range against the second.

For a Palindrome, you only have to check half (rounded down) of the characters.

`rbegin` is a reverse iterator -- it iterates over the string in reverse order.

Comment: Though the compiler should hopefully optimise them down to the same code after automatic inlining, using the three-pronged form is certainly more concise and no less safe. Maybe also a word about preferring `std::string_view` over `std::string const&`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything wrong with your current approach. You might have better luck asking about feedback on your working code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but since you're also asking about broken code I can assist there.

You can construct a `std::string` using reverse iterators:

```
std::string reversed(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
```

So you don't need to create a string, then call call `std::reverse`

You can also more simply just use `return str == rstr`, or `return str == rstr ? true : false;`, but I dislike the latter cause it's just silly. If something is true then true? Just `return str == rstr`.

Comment: Yes, and all the relevant requests for reviews should be here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrome%20c%2b%2b

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard template library, you could just check the first half of the vector against the second half of the vector as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool isPalindrome(const std::string &str)
{
  auto itStop = str.begin() + str.size() / 2;
  auto itBegin = str.begin();
  auto itReverse = str.rbegin();
  while (itBegin != itStop) {
    if (*itBegin != *itReverse)
      return false;
    else {
      itBegin++;
      itReverse++;
    }
  }

  return true;

}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> string_vector{{"am I ma"},
                                   {"amIma"},
                                   {"amIIma"},
                                   {"amI ma"}};

  for(const auto& str: string_vector) {
    std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" is " <<
      (isPalindrome(str) ? "" : "not ") <<
      "a palindrome." << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
"am I ma" is a palindrome.
"amIma" is a palindrome.
"amIIma" is a palindrome.
"amI ma" is not a palindrome.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it manually?

- We search until `i < str_length/2`, because it is sufficient both for even and odd length strings (for example `length=4` will search `str[0]` and `str[1]`. `length=5` will also search `str[0]` and `str[1]` - no need to check `str[2]` because of symmetry).
- `int str_length = str.length();` is used to save the length of the string, so that it is not computed in every iteration. Useful for pretty long strings.

```
bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str)
{
    int str_length = str.length();
    for (int i=0; i<str_length/2; i++) {
        if (str[i]!=str[str_length-1-i]) // Checks "opposite" letters
            return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```